# ICDevice not ready

Tags: cocoa

I'm trying to write a simple Cocoa App to scan some documents from my USB-scanner. I use it the same way as this example of apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/ScannerBrowser/Listings/AppController_m.html

The 'deviceBrowser:didAddDevice...' method is called. There I set the scanners delegate to self (like in the example), but the methods 'deviceDidBecomeReady' or 'scannerDeviceDidBecomeAvailable' are never called.

Is there anything I have forgotten?

Here is the code:

http://pastebin.com/NHZ0j5ze

Comment: If you start with the Apple code, what happens?

Comment: Nothing! As well only didAddDevice... and around 30 seconds after pressing the open button: "Failed to open a session on the device"

Answer (score 0):

Oh... reading the .h-files of the frameworks should still be the first option. The order was wrong and I forgot didOpenSessionWithError.

Here is the working code:
http://pastebin.com/NDEY5S13